# Can we upload and read Excel file in corda?

Tags: kotlin, corda

I just need to read an Excel file and store the values in to a variable or to an array (values will be numbers). How it can be done in Corda

Answer (score 0):

you can read it using any csv reading library, e.g. Apache commons csv, OpenCsv etc... If you need to store the actual file, then you can upload it as an attachment to a node and share it where required.